# How to set property value while object initialization outside view lifecycle?

Tags: swift

I have a ViewController with 2 fields:

```swift
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    private var dataManager = MyDataManager()
    private var dateFormatter: DateFormatter?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale.current
        dateFormatter.dateStyle = .medium
    }
}
```

How can I initialize `dateFormatter` outside `viewDidLoad()` like `dataManager` does?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a define and call initializer.

```
private let dateFormatter: DateFormatter = {
   let d = DateFormatter()
   d.locale = NSLocale.current
   d.dateStyle = .medium
   return d
}()
```